# Express JS How to push object to an array of child object

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a school directory and I want to push objects to my locations array, which is a property of my child object Floor that belongs to a Parent Object called Map.

Floor Schema

```
const floorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    file:{
      type:String,
      required:true
    },
    floorSlug:{
      type:String,
      required:true,
    },
    locations:[{
        locationTitle: String,
        locationSlug: String,
        description: String,
        position_x: String,
        position_y: String,
        position_z: String,
    }],
})
```

My route to add location objects stands like this which I tried to "edit the floor", specifically trying to push to the locations property:

```
router.patch('/:slug/:floorSlug/add-location', (req, res) => {
  const slug = req.params.slug;
  const { floorSlug } = req.body;
  const querySlug = '^' + slug + '$';
  const locations = req.body.locations;
  Map.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        $and: [
          { "slug": { '$regex': querySlug, $options: 'i' } },
          { 'floorSlug': floorSlug }]
      },
      {
        $push: { "locations": locations }
      }
  )
  .then(map => {
    map.floors.push({
      locations
    })
    map.save()
      .then(map => res.json(map))
      .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))

});
```

My expected result should look like this:

```
    {
    "map": [
        {
            "floors": [
                {
                    "title": "upper level",
                    "file": "mapurl.com",
                    "floorSlug": "upper-level"
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "locationTitle": "title",
                            "locationSlug": "title-1",
                            "description": "description",
                            "position_x": "1",
                            "position_y": "1",
                            "position_z": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "lower level",
                    "file": "mapurl.com",
                    "floorSlug": "lower-level",
                    "locations": [
                        {
                            "locationTitle": "title",
                            "locationSlug": "title-1",
                            "description": "description",
                            "position_x": "1",
                            "position_y": "1",
                            "position_z": "1"
                        }
                        {
                            "locationTitle": "title",
                            "locationSlug": "title-2",
                            "description": "description",
                            "position_x": "2",
                            "position_y": "2",
                            "position_z": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "_id": "61cfb0911dfb0970a0eb00cb",
            "title": "map",
            "slug": "map-1",
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) takes element(s) as arguments that should be added to the array - looks like you're passing a callback function as the argument instead, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

I think this code may help you !

```
router.patch('/:slug/:floorSlug/add-location', (req, res) => {
  const slug = req.params.slug;
  const { floorSlug } = req.body;
  const querySlug = '^' + slug + '$';
  const locations = req.body.locations;
  Map.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      $and: [
        { "slug": { '$regex': querySlug, $options: 'i' } },
        { 'floors.floorSlug': floorSlug }]
    },
    {
      $push: { 'floors.$.locations': locations }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this helped me find the locations property, but I want to push an object to the array of locations. how can I define that?

Comment: Using `$push` you can push the object in `locations` array !

Comment: thanks a lot, I have updated my code and I was wondering if im saving properly?

Comment: @AlbertoRamos i update my answer !  if my answer help you accept it !

Comment: this is still pushing a new a new object everytime I do a patch request. can you show me how to save it properly? Please check my updated code

Comment: Now I have an error using that code: "Cannot read property 'floors' of null"